# empty source port with sending udp data (lwip, Cortex M3, Stellaris LM3S6965 Evaluation Board)

Tags: c, sockets, udp, port, lwip

I'm working with Cortex M3, Stellaris® LM3S6965 Evaluation Board. I'm sending an UDP packet to my pc. That works because I checked it with wireshark. But what I do see is that I don't have a source port. And I have no clue how so solve this.

I call this function to sent the a udp packet

```
void send_udp(){
    RIT128x96x4Enable(1000000);
    RIT128x96x4StringDraw("UDP data verzonden..", 0, 40, 15);

    struct ip_addr  serverIp;
    IP4_ADDR(&serverIp,192,168,1,100);

    u16_t port;
    port = 64000;
    struct udp_pcb * pcb;
    pcb = udp_new();

    udp_bind(pcb, &serverIp, port);
    udp_recv(pcb, udp_echo_recv, NULL);
    struct pbuf *p;
    char msg[]="request";

    //Allocate packet buffer
    p = pbuf_alloc(PBUF_TRANSPORT,sizeof(msg),PBUF_RAM);
    memcpy (p->payload, msg, sizeof(msg));
    udp_sendto(pcb, p, &serverIp, port);
    pbuf_free(p); //De-allocate packet buffer
}
```

Wireshark example of packet: [(click here to enlarge)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1Rk6.png)
[image: here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also saw that "time to live" in the ipv4 pcb was 0. 
So I added this line,

```
pcb->ttl = UDP_TTL; // Time to live
```

This solved my issue

Answer (score 2):

The call to `udp_bind()` should assign the local port, but it seems to be failing for you.

The number you're using (64000) is in the range called [dynamic, private or ephemeral ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Dynamic.2C_private_or_ephemeral_ports), which might be why it's not working as expected.

From the documentation, `udp_bind()` supports port number 0 to get a dynamically assigned number; this is typically the way to go if the source port isn't important.